# Project Doesn't Build in Android Studio 2.3.1 at all

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-2.3

Yesterday I updated my Android Studio version from 2.3 to 2.3.1 and today when I tried to create a **New Project** this [image: familiar screen] familiar screen should disappear after sometime but it didn't disappeared after 30 minutes of waiting. Anyhow I managed to close android studio by Task Manager and started Android Studio again and created a new project again and the same thing happened again.

Although when I open my previous projects again they are working fine but the problem is with the **new project creation** only. I am having a good working internet connection along with the latest version of gradle 3.4.1

Any idea why this would be happening?

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this "problem" with android studio but after looking here and there I found out that when I update gradle version for my project, for example from 2.2 to 2.2.1, if I do not have that gradle version already android studio tries to download gradle distribution for that version to build the project and since I have poor internet connection, it was the download which was taking time. 
Maybe your android studio is downloading the gradle too and it takes time.